# How to protect edit user profile route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm building an app where a logged in user can edit their own profile and of course unable to edit another user's profile.

I have this following route :

```
http://2mark.dev/profile/derp22/edit
```

The problem with that route is that the route is accessible by another users and and will finally allow the other users to the edit "derp22" profile data. My question is how to protect this route so that the other users can't access it ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can either make a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware) or a [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization). Your objective would be a simple `if` check to see whether the logged in user indeed owns the profile that's being edited. Check out the docs :)

Comment: From my experience, `/profile/{user_id}` isn't a route; rather `/profile/edit`, and the controller associated with that route will return the logged in User's details. That way, there's no possibility of entering another user's ID and editing their information. Use another route for that, like `/user/{user_id}/edit`

Comment: Don't pass sensible information in URL, Just get it from current session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this in the method in your profile controller.

Here is the methodology:

```
1. Get the current user.
2. Get the user you want to edit.
3. Check against those Id's.
4. Throw/return error message or proceed in method.
```

Example:

```
$currentUser = \Auth::user();
$user        = User::findOrFail($id);

if ($user->id != $currentUser->id) {
    abort(403);
}

// Then have the save method.
```

https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ProfilesController.php

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#via-the-user-model

or

You can compare if the authenticated user id is equal the id